# Is there a way to identify all variables in a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question:

I'm trying to write a python program that accepts a python file name and returns all the user-defined variables in that file. I know that I can use the dir() function to get all the variable names in a specific file. I would like to do this on files that already exist.

Use Case:

I am going to replace a ton of underscored variables to cammel case variables.
(ex: total_taxes should be changed to totalTaxes).

I will then write the python files with the new standardized variable names.

Comment: "ast" module may help.

Comment: `print(locals)` on every file should help

Comment: Not to knock your use case, particular if this is just something you're doing for fun, but why would you change your files *away* from the standard Python style convention?

Comment: I am just doing this on all of my python files to make them standardized. I guess i could do it in the other direction. It is just for fun mostly. I am still a very new programmer.  @NickBailey

Comment: @NickBailey I didn't realize there was a suggested naming standard (just searched it up). That's helpful!

Comment: @LuisFelipe would I add "print(locals)" to the end of every file or could it be done in my main that is modifying all the other files.

Comment: is difficult to control from main, i cant think on a fast way to do it

Comment: @AustinO you can fast edit with a python script all files opening them in read mode and appending `print(filename,locals)` to a txt files and run them all to write in this file, then opening this file in pandas and making your desired task

Comment: also, editors like `Pycharm` allows you to rename variables finding their whole usage on the scrips. This funcion is called `refactor`

Comment: Your just for fun exercise can provide **a lot of learning**. **Note:** `print(locals)` will not help much because locals can change within every function. Each function would have to be run and locals evaluated. I suggest the key is to remember two things: `1.` A python programmer should do things the pythonic way. (Search for PEP8 and PEP20) `2.`  Programs, are scripts, are modules, are text files. Once you are doing things the pythonic way process those files. 'imports should always be one line so this will be easy to find. If variables are one line they will be easy to find etc.